# Как создать 2 таблицы с одинаковым набором полей в одном MS SQL скрипте

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется 2 скрипта:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    Id INT,
    Age INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(20),
    LastName NVARCHAR(20),
    Email VARCHAR(30),
    Phone VARCHAR(20)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE _Customers
(
    Id INT,
    Age INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(20),
    LastName NVARCHAR(20),
    Email VARCHAR(30),
    Phone VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Хочется заменить 2 определения полей одним, чтобы избежать ошибок при изменении одной из таблиц (набор полей всегда должен быть одинаковым).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE _Customers LIKE Customers;

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но ваш синтаксис похоже для MySQL, я же имел в виду T-SQL

Comment: Вы об этом нигде не написали, потому скорее всего Вам и не ответили больше ничего. Поправьте свое сообщение и уточните что вам нужен MS SQL или какой-то другой и я думаю, найдутся люди которые вам предложат варианты, сори я не посмотрел что у вас там NVARCHAR, но все-равно не очень то понятно с описание задачи что надо решать в конкретном решении.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/30638/ пишут что можно так 

select * into [destinationTable] from [sourceTable] where 0 = 1

Answer (score 0):

Может такой вариант вам подойдет:

```
DECLARE @table1 VARCHAR(100)='Customers',@table2 VARCHAR(100)='_Customers';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)=
    N'CREATE TABLE @table
    (
        Id INT,
        Age INT,
        FirstName NVARCHAR(20),
        LastName NVARCHAR(20),
        Email VARCHAR(30),
        Phone VARCHAR(20)
    )';
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX)=REPLACE(@sql,'@table',@table1);
DECLARE @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX)=REPLACE(@sql,'@table',@table2);

EXEC(@sql1);
EXEC(@sql2);
```